# My NVidia mobile graphics with Haswell CPU won't work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04

I installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo Y410P (Haswell CPU, NVidia GT750M, Windows 8 and UEFI) and after boot the screen just turned off instead of showing Unity. I messed around  lot, and with nomodeset could sometimes get a display to come up, but it was the wrong size. I was so confused that I uninstalled, but Windows is dreadful and not able to do everything I do in Ubuntu. The OS I used was stock Ubuntu 13.04, which I would prefer to use, although elementaryOS 0.2 (12.04.2 derivative) is also acceptable. Any ideas?
(Sorry for posting this new question but I am so confused and can't find any answers elsewhere.
Edit: So now I reinstalled with 12.04.2, on my phone now but will try nomodeset to install when I get home.

Comment: Try 12.04, I have had more success with 12.04 and nvidia cards.

Comment: Well with 12.04 at least I can do a normal boot... to terminal.

Comment: can you boot with the nomodeset option and try installing the nvidia driver.

Comment: I'll try when I get home.

Comment: Hm, I think installing Nvidia drivers may not work with once. Haswell CPU has a built-in GPU right? In other words, you have Optimus.. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Answer (score 4):

Press function and the up arrow key (brightness). I had the same issue on my Y510p and discovered by accident that the screen brightness defaults to off upon boot.

Answer (score 0):

Yo.. I got it to work..

It's the problem with the Nvidia graphics card.

1. Download and install Nvidia graphics card from Nvidia website or wherever.
2. What you need to do is remove the Nouveau (Intel driver) which is clashing with Nvidia during load (I think that's the problem because I check my logs it seems that it's unable to load Nvidia) so.

   ```
   sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
   ```

then restart your machine. WALLA!

also, i had mesa installed as well beforehand to get glx to get me what I need.

from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: I have similar laptop: Y510P with Intel Graphics + Nvidia, what I did was install & activate the intel driver, which is fine for non-games. Then I installed the nvidia driver alongside bumblebee, which allows me to activate the nvidia card for certain applications. See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/346382/lenovo-y510p-and-sli-gt750m-not-working/383966#383966